# Tables' relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I develop simple DB and I have confused with next issue: I have separated entities(tables) for `'Employe'`, `'Author'` and `'Manager'`. In table 'Employe' I have column 'Appointment' that can containe some vocation in particular `'Author'` and `'Manager'` (but it also can containe another vocation for example `'Seller'`, `'CopyRighter'` etc). How can I implement it in my DB? What relationships have I use?

Comment: Is it possible to combine Author and Manager Entities in single table?

Comment: @voo How can I differentiate them later?

Comment: Create Id field RoleID and RoleName in new Roles table, and assign them as a keys in your single table

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider abstracting your vocations into a `Role` table. Cosider the following structure:

```
RoleID | RoleName
   1   |  Author
   2   |  Manager  
   3   |  Copyrighter
etc...
```

Then your `Appointment` column of the `Employee` table will contain a foreign key (`RoleID`) to this `Role` table:

Comment: Ye? it's look nice but it is only an answer for question 'How can I fill in Appointment column of Employe table?'. In my case I have separated tables for 'Manager'and 'Author' related to 'Contract' entity and some extra ones. Is it no necessity to create some extra relationship between 'Manager', 'Author' and 'Role' table(that you add)?